# Writing usb on FreeBSD to access on windows

Tags: ubuntu, freebsd, usb

How can I write "stuff" into USB drive on FreeBSD such that, the "stuff" is accessible in Windows [*yes my wife still uses that :(* ] and Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Windows can only mount FAT variants and NTFS natively. Non-native filesystems exist but require going through hoops to the point that it's often simpler to install a Linux (or FreeBSD) VM. So, pick FAT32 or NTFS.

The FUSE NTFS-3g driver is available on FreeBSD as a port ([`fusefs-ntfs`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/ports/sysutils/fusefs-ntfs/)), as are the associated utilities ([`ntfsprogs`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/ports/sysutils/ntfsprogs/)).

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just format it with `newfs_msdos` (you can even format whole drive, without any partitioning scheme).